# Moving multiple table data from one database to another database by stored procedure using SSIS packages

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a stored procedure which gets data from table trans of database "A" and inserts into multiple tables (trans, trans_log, trans_history)  in database "B" and then this procedure just deletes that data from the trans table in database "A". This is just an archive process. The procedure `RETURN`s 0 if successful.

Previously it was scheduled as a SQL job, but now I need to create an SSIS package for it. How to create SSIS package for this? I know that I need to create source and destination connection in a dataflow, but I am stuck at mapping columns, my procedure does not any return columns it just inserts into multiple table of another database.

How do I define source and destination or how do I perform this in SSIS package?

Comment: Sounds like you need an Execute T-SQL Task, not a Data Flow Task. Though just having an SSIS package, which has a single Execute T-SQL Task to call a procedure seems somewhat pointless; you might as well leave the execution of the procedure in agent.

Comment: How to specify source and destination connection for Execute T-SQL Task

Comment: Execute T-SQL Tasks don't have a source or destination.

Comment: but in my case two different database which in turn need two connection right.? , can you please provide any link for Execute - SQL Task.

Comment: *"but in my case two different database which in turn need two connection right."* You said that logic is already all in your procedure, so you just want to **execute** that procedure, right? So you just need to define your connection manager for the instance that procedure is on, and then have the [Execute T-SQL Statement Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-t-sql-statement-task?view=sql-server-ver16) execute that procedure.